# How to read appsettings.json for .net core 2.1 mvc application to be deployed on Azure WebApp for Linux

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am creating .net core 2.1 MVC application.

Deployment would be done on Web APP for Linux on Azure.

What is the right way to read Application Settings in code because in my appsettings.json i can not keep sensitive info like username , password etc..
Also some of my keys are hierachical like  : xyz tag under that Rids and then key values.

[image]

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": 
  {
   "DefaultConnection": "connection key here"
  },

  "abc": 
  {
   "apiKey": "some value",
   "apiSecret": "some value",
   "appName": "some value",
  },
 "xyz": {
      "UserName": "some value",
       "Password": "some value",
      "RIds": {
                "a": "some value",
                "b": "some value",
                "c": "some value"
               },    
      "ClientSecret": "some value"
         }   
 }
```

Comment: since my deployment is on linux  i managed to read the key say "apiKey" using below code 'services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);'  in startup.cs and 'IConfiguration config' as parameter in constructor, 'Config["apiKey"];' to read the key.

Comment: However i still could not read xyz__UserName on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can read the hierarchical configuration data. The first is shown in the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#hierarchical-configuration-data)

You can read the sub keys via the Config array as:

```
Config["xyz:UserName"]
Config["xyq:RIds:a"]
```

Another alternative is to create a class the represents the data you are trying to load:

```
public class Xyz
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public RIds RIds { get; set; }
}

public class RIds
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

In `startup.cs` you can load the configuration into your class and inject it into any other classes that need it:

```
public Configure(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddConfiguration<Xyz>(Configuration.GetSection("xyz"));
}
```

Now you can access it in a class using the `IOptions<T>` class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Xyz _config;

    public MyClass(IOptions<Xyz> options)
    {
        _config = options.Value;

        var username = _config.UserName;
    }
}
```

This also works when you define the settings in Azure appsettings. To get the hierarchy you need to use the `:` to identify the relationship e.g.

```
xyz:UserName
xyz:Password
```

All the configuration information is available on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

You can read about `IOptions<T>` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: : works in windows deployment not on Linux. Mine is Linux

Comment: Replace the : with __ (double underscore). That should work on all platforms

Comment: : does not work on linux and __ does not work on windows